# Vectorization or For loop in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vectorization

I want to read data from .txt file to plot a 3D graph in matlab. The data looks like this

```
T_hor     T_ver   V_hor   V_ver
 8,833   -15,43  -11,871  23,604    
 3,121   -22,78  -9,949   41,712   
-8,012   -26,28  -4,317   33,790   
-12,697  -20,99   6,948   22,314   
-11,960   5,68    2,079   0,469   
 4,279   -22,17  -10,002  39,791
```

Each column I've imported as a separate column Vector say T_hor,T_ver,V_hor,V_ver. Now I want to read  first 4096 rows of this individual column vector 'T_hor'  and then the next 4096 rows of the column vector T_hor. This applies for every column. My Goal was to compute FFT for the 4096 set of values incrementally and store them as column vectors.I was previously using this command to read the values into  different column vector.

```
x1 = T_ver(1:4096);
x2 = T_ver(4097:8193);
```

I want to make the code look more Logical and avoid unnecessary lines of code. So I tried applying **for loop** for this but I think I'm doing it in a wrong way.

```
for X
X = (1:LastValue:4096);
end
```

I think Vectorization can be more easy and consumes less execution time. Can anyone give me a direction or hints on how to implement this.

Comment: I think you want to do something like `X = reshape(T_ver, 4096, 6);`

Comment: What exactly is consuming time for you? Isn't that the I/O reading from the text file?

Comment: @Divakar. Defining each set of column vector individually. I've around 1300000 rows in a column vector. Now I want to read only 4096 values at a time and then next 40960 values.

Comment: @Naveh  reshape is won't work in my case I guess because I've already have a column vector of 1x1300000. Now I want to only read the first 4096 values and then the next with Looping or may be Vectorization.

Comment: It indeed won't work if your vector is not exactly 4096*6 as you want it. Try `X = reshape(T_ver(1:4096*6), 4096, 6);`. You can then loop on this statement to get more 4096*6 chunks, changing the indices in `T_ver` appropriately.

Comment: But how to Loop it now by vectorization?

Comment: Look at the documentation for [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html). I assumed you wanted to reshape the first 4096*6 elements of `T_var` into an matrix with 4096 rows and 6 columns. This is what the expression I wrote does. If this is not what you had in mind, please clarify this in the question.

Comment: it might be easier to help if we know what you're doing with `x1` and `x2`

Comment: Do `fft(reshape(T_hor,4096,[]))`, which would give you a 2D matrix, let's say `T_hor_out` and then inside loop where you would hopefully use those FFT values, use `T_hor_out(:,iter)` instead, where `iter` would be your loop iterator.

Comment: @Divakar. I tried using your hints. I get this error "Undefined function or variable 'iter'." I tried to find help on this 'iter' command in the documentation and nothing was found. Is there any loop operator where I could iterate them column-wise.

Comment: As I said earlier, **`"iter would be your loop iterator"`**, which means  `for iter = 1:N`as the loop you talked about!!

Comment: @yoh.lej.I'm trying to plot a 3d waterfall ( Cascade) plot with frequency on X axis, Y- axis would be Magnitude and the Z axis would be time . I wanted to do FFT on the Signal taking only say 4096 samples at a time and then plot the curve and then for the next set of 4096 samples will come next.. So when we overlap all These waves...we get a waterfall graph. Here Frequency axis is same for all the sets of data. But amplitude would be changing for every set of 4096 samples. so the end graph would be something overlapping of all these data points in 3D space with different amplitudes

Comment: @Divakar   I used the the for loop as follows                                                          `fftx=fft(reshape(T_hor,4096,[]));`
`for i= 1:28`
`%Xn value of the complex signal`
`Xn = abs(fftx(:,i));`
`end`            But it reads only the last column (i=28) and ends up.